# angular ng-required radio button not toggling required off in firefox 33, OK in chrome

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firefox

I am trying to toggle the required attribute on a radio button using Angular to show the HTML5 popup.

I cannot get the following code to function correctly in Firefox 33.  It does function correctly in Chrome.  The required property is being toggled via the checkbox value, in Firefox, when set to false the radio button still acts as required and shows the HTML5 required popup.  See the plnkr below for example which doesn't work for me in ff 33.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
<script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.1" src="//code.angularjs.org/1.3.1/angular.js"></script>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="myApp">
  <script>
angular.module('myApp',[])
.controller('myController',['$scope',function($scope) {
  $scope.fooRequired=true;

  $scope.submitForm = function() {
    $scope.submitMessage = "submitted";
  }
}]);
  </script>
  <form name="myForm" ng-submit="submitForm()" ng-controller="myController">
<h1>Required Toggle in Firefox 33 no work. OK in Chrome</h1>
<p>toggle required in firefox to off, does validation for required still kick in? </p>
<br/>
<input type="radio" ng-required="fooRequired" name="foo" ng-model="foo" ng-value="true" > true
<input type="radio" ng-required="fooRequired" name="foo" ng-model="foo" ng-value="false" > false
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="fooRequired"/>toggle required
<button type="submit">Submit</button>

Required? {{fooRequired}}
<br/>
{{submitMessage}}

</form>    
  </body>

</html>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/tBlM5KXb5DLP1Hb8ta8U?p=preview

I opened a ticket at mozilla as a response from Angular was that it might be browser bug. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1100535

Comment: The `ng-valid-required` and `ng-invalid-required` classes are set correctly and the `required` attribute is correctly removed and added. Looks like a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was fixed in firefox 36+